# wired ethernet interface not detected by lshw, lspci

Tags: drivers, ethernet, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Satellite PSAG8U-04001W.

No eth* interface shows up on ifconfig.

```
$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2544 (2.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2544 (2.4 KiB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:6b:d3:1b:dc  
          inet addr:192.168.1.83  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:6bff:fed3:1bdc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27901 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20958957 (19.9 MiB)  TX bytes:3551000 (3.3 MiB)
```

Even more surprinsingly, neither lshw nor lspci shows anything related to wired ethernet controller/adapter:
lshw:

```
$lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan2
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:6b:d3:1b:dc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-4-amd64 firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.83 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:d4600000-d4601fff
```

lspci:

```
$lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: i915
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a43] (rev 07)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
   Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2942] (rev 03)
   Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 03)
   Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2939] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller [8086:2919] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2929] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
   Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1201]
   Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
04:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832] (rev 05)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
04:06.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 22)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
04:06.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter [1180:0592] (rev 12)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: r592
04:06.3 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller [1180:0852] (rev 12)
   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
   Kernel driver in use: r852
```

Why is my laptop's wired ethernet not showing? How can I debug this?

The installation of Debian wasn't originally on this system: it was on an older laptop whose motherboard fried, so I rescued the hard drive as well as the Debian installation. However, I doubt this should have anything to do with lspci not even detecting the wired eth controller.

Comment: Are you sure that the wired network card hasn't been disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: The last time I checked this Toshiba bios had a pretty limited set of options, and I don't recall anything about the network card. But I will check again.

Comment: actually, you were right! apparently there is an option to disable something like "built-in LAN", which was checked. Can you please add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the wired network card hasn't been disabled in the BIOS.